# How to to import RXJS operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

When using RXJS which is the best way to import lettable operators? Is there any difference in performance between both options bellow?

```
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';
```

I am using the rxjs version 5.5.6

Comment: Even better discussed here this https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3018

Comment: Thanks, exactly my question.